# touchesBegan function in Swift doesn't need override

Tags: swift, cocoa-touch

I'm new to Xcode and I've been playing around with making a SpriteKit game in Swift.

In every tutorial or Stack overflow topic I've looked at, the touchesBegan function has an override before it, but when I copy that code into GameScene.swift, I get an error, "override can only be specified on class members," with an auto-fix of deleting "override."

So instead of this:`override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {...}`

it wants me to have this:`func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {...}`

I'm not sure why this is happening, and I don't know if it will affect how the function works.

My current code in GameScene.swift is:

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

override init(size: CGSize) {
    super.init(size: size)
    backgroundColor = SKColor.blackColor()
    let stars = Stars()

    var starNode:SKNode!
    starNode = stars.createStars(CGFloat(30), direction: 1, scaleX: self.frame.width, scaleY: self.frame.height)
    addChild(starNode)

    func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
         //Nothing here yet
     } 
   }
}
```

Is there something else I am missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Your code will work fine as is.

Comment: I cannot find `touchesBegan` in your sample code. Can you add it?

Comment: Oops, I must have not copied it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must close the second init with a `}` after `addChild(starNode)`. Your code should read:

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override init(size: CGSize) {
        super.init(size: size)
        backgroundColor = SKColor.blackColor()
        // let stars = Stars()

        var starNode:SKNode!
        starNode = stars.createStars(CGFloat(30), direction: 1, 
                          scaleX: self.frame.width, scaleY: self.frame.height)
        addChild(starNode)
    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        //Nothing here yet
    }
}
```